# Find the limit of $a_{n + 1} = \frac{{1 + a_n + a_n b_n }}{{b_n }} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be two sequences defined by the recurrence relation 
\begin{align}
a_{n + 1}  = \frac{{1 + a_n  + a_n b_n }}{{b_n }},\qquad b_{n + 1}  = \frac{{1 + b_n  + a_n b_n }}{{a_n }}
\end{align}
with $a_1=1$ and $b_1=2$. Find $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } a_n$.

---

Simple manipulations yield that 
\begin{align}
a_n  = \frac{{1 + b_n }}{{b_{n + 1}  - b_n }},\qquad b_n  = \frac{{1 + a_n }}{{a_{n + 1}  - a_n }}
\end{align}
I tried to find the first few terms of $a_n$ and $b_n$ but it seem that they doesn't have a general form.  Once can see that both sequences increasing fast and randomly. 
Also, I tried to insert $b_n$ in $a_n$, but I got a complicated result and it doesn't help or indicate to anything.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Almost immediately you can deduce (with a bit of induction) that $a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1+a_n}{b_n}>0$

Comment: and $$b_{n+1}-b_n=\frac{1+b_n}{a_n}>0$$

Comment: yes, it's ok thanks all.